# Building location searchable site

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax

Hi there Stack peers!

I am working on creating an apartment review site something along the lines of [Apartment Guide](http://www.apartmentguide.com/). I am EXTREMELY new to coding and to this site so bear with me.

My main question is what are the languages involved in creating a site such as [Apartment Guide](http://www.apartmentguide.com/). I would like to get on learning them ASAP, but first I need to identify the necessary ones.

I am especially looking at the search functionality of the site which allows search by zip, city, apartment name etc. I am thinking the search is a JS function to a sql directory of all the apartments in their database? No idea.

I ran through css and HTML off udemy and codeacademy, I can survive in that field with a reference guide. Right now, I am currently learning JavaScript at the moment but I would like to get more hands on by coding since reading from a 700+ page book isnt sticking quite so well even with notes and the examples. (headfirst into JS by O'reilly).

Again, super new at programming so bear with me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let's start with the following question. `I am thinking the search is a JS function to a sql directory of all the apartments in their database?` Who are 'they' from whom you want to take database?

Comment: Ah I see how my question could have been confusing. 
'They' in this case would be Apartment Guide. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

So far, you have begun to look at the parts of a website that are at the receiving end. HTML, CSS and Javascript are all interpreted by web browsers on the device of the person requesting the resource. You also need to learn how a remote server generates the information for the resource, which can then be passed through the web server to the requester.

You may need to read a few more books before you are through. It is probably too early for you to be focused on the search functionality of  your site. There are lots of parts to a web site and most people have their favourite languages/technologies. I like the so-called "LAMP" (e.g. Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP) stack of technologies, mostly because I found a low barrier to start using them.

Why don't you try learning by setting up a very simple MySQL database on a server, and using a scripting language like php or perl to pull some text out of the database and present it in a web page on a browser.

If you can do this, then you you are handling the "round trip" of sending a request from a browser and getting a response. You can then move on to learning how to send variables along with the request and then have the script act on those variables to modify what is returned to the browser.

You are at the start of a long and fun road. This is not something you will be able to learn in a week. However, fairly soon, my explanation may seem too simple and you will need more details (and have more questions).

Comment: Hi Wmorse,    Thanks for taking the time to respond! I appreciate it. So, I should continue with JS obviously as Im almost through my first book on it, then work on scripting and understanding server "round trip" funcitonality. Gotcha.

Comment: Would you recommend another book for the addtl languages or interactive learning through somewhere like Code Academy? Im just looking for the most efficient way to learn. I cant wait to start/finish my project.                                                                                                                                            Could you give me a list of languages that are a MUST to learn to construct a site like Apartment Guide. And how to deal with video functionality for another site, such as uploading videos and the like.